# Is there a way to make a Script trigger On Collision?(2D, c#, unity, personal project)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have searched on the internet for an answer to this and as im not very advanced in unity or c#.

I have a player obj with a player camera on it as a child (all 2d), there camera has a few scripts that alter "rendering"(visual effect on screen), but i only want it to trigger when the player obj collides with a specific obj.

I have tried using variables to bypass this, but it hasnt worked, at all.

example of the script that is attached to the camera:

```
private Texture texture;        #camerarender i think
private Material material;      #camerarender i think
public oscilattion os;


void Awake ()
{
    material = new Material( Shader.Find("Hidden/Tint") );
}

// Postprocess the image
void OnRenderImage (RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
{

    material.SetFloat("_ValueX", os.osci() * y);
    material.SetFloat("_ValueY", os.osci() * u);
    material.SetFloat("_ValueZ", os.osci() * v);

    Graphics.Blit (source, destination, material);
}
```

player has an OnCollision (player only has one script called move for now):

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "phase1")
    {
        Debug.Log("collision with phase1");    //not working
        cam.GetComponent<ShaderEffect_Tint>(); //atempt to start the script
    }

}
```

variables in move.cs script that doesnt trigger the collision or activate the script:

```
 public float speed;
Rigidbody2D rb;
public float jumpForce;
bool isGrounded = false;
public Transform isGroundedChecker;
public float checkGroundRadius;
public LayerMask groundLayer;
public Collider2D phase1;
public int trip = 0;
//
public float y = 1;
public float u = 1;
public float v = 1;
//  public bool swapUV = false;
private Material material;
public oscilattion os;
public ShaderEffect_Tint shaderEffect_Tint;
public Camera cam;
```

some examples of things i have tried:

-have the script always run and try to change a variable that makes it do nothing to something that makes it work.

-call the camera and the script in different ways to try and use it

-do the OnCollision in the camera

edit-----(extra information)

Player has a collider and rigidbody, phase1 is an obj with the same tag and also has a collider but with "is trigger" checked.

The debug line doesnt work on a simple OnCollisionEnter2D.

The player and the

Im at a loss of what to do, all i really want is to trigger a script on a camera with a collision.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information. Does your player have a Rigidbody2D attached? Are you sure the spelling of "phase1" is correct, including letter case (upper lower case)?

Comment: i checked phase1 and its spelled right, i edited like this, is it better?

Comment: Move the log outside the if condition. Does the collsiion itself halppen? 
`private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    Debug.Log("collision happening");
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "phase1")
    {
        Debug.Log("collision with phase1");    //not working
        cam.GetComponent<ShaderEffect_Tint>(); //atempt to start the script
    }

}`

Comment: i took the Private part away, but i dont think it does since the debug.log doesnt happen, inside or outside of if

Comment: If the Debug log isn't firing you have an issue with the actual collision detection, troubleshoot it and get that to fire, check the physics layers, tags, that the player has a Rigidbody, etc